# SDL 2 (Win32) hosted in WPF not receiving keyboard input

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, winapi, sdl

I have a WPF application that hosts an SDL2 (Win32) application. SDL renders to the WPF user control and received input from the mouse but not the keyboard. SDL is reading events using SDL_PollEvent. It’s worth noting that SDL_GetKeyboardState also doesn’t work.

https://github.com/Nicks108/WPF-SDL-Host  (Linked to the repo)

Iv been struggling with this for a few days and can’t seem to figure out what’s going on.
According to Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/wpf-and-win32-interoperation?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#hosting_an_hwnd)
“In general, while input devices are scoped within the HwndHost hosted Win32 region, input events go directly to Win32.” Which implies that the keyboard isn’t scoped to the SDL win32 control, but the mouse is?

I’ve tried overloading WndProc and connecting to my RenderSurfacesHost MessageHook event.
From experimenting, it seems that I can stop SDL receiving mouse inputs by setting the handled Bool to true for all messages. Since this method should be called for all unhandled messages, it implies that the mouse is not being handled in the programme until it gets to my RenderSurfacesHost, but the is, somewhere else.

How can I pass keyboard input from WPF to my win32 code, so that SDL can read the events with SDL_PoolEvent?